# instrument a java lambda using ASM

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, invokedynamic, symbolic-execution

I'm adding support for instrumenting invokedynamic in a concolic engine and the way we currently instrument is by using a custom classloader that finds the resource related to that class in the class path but as the lambda is a synthetic class created on the fly it's not actually there.

Do you know how to instrument invoke dynamic generated classes? I've seen that using agents may be an option but i want to be sure that i can't reuse what I already have.

Comment: Those generated classes are simple, and just invoke an other method that you probably did already implement.

Comment: You can’t instrument those generated classes, neither statically nor using agents, and there’s no point in trying. The body of the lambda expression is not part of the generated class.